# Need help in updating table based on the values from another table using ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

TABLE A (ID,AMT),
TABLE B (ID, QTY)

I need to multiply A.AMT with B.QTY and update those values on TABLE A. The ID cols are equal in A and B. This is the query that I have created:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.AMT = 
   (SELECT A.AMT * B.QTY AS A
             FROM B JOIN A
                    ON
                 A.ID=B.ID)
           WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT A.AMT * B.QTY AS A
               FROM B JOIN A
                    ON
                A.ID=B.ID)
```

On execution it returns an error: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Could someone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, re-using the same table names without aliases over and over again is hard to look through. It may also be causing you some confusion. So I'll try to break it down. Start with this from your existing statement:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.AMT =   (SELECT A.AMT * B.QTY AS A
                 FROM B 
                    JOIN A ON A.ID=B.ID)
```

You are setting a.amount = a calculation on EVERY matching A/B pair because you are not ensuring that this query is related to the ID of the row you are updating! This is where your error is coming from. Instead:

```
UPDATE A a1
SET a1.AMT =   (SELECT A2.AMT * B.QTY AS tot_amt
                  FROM B 
                    JOIN A A2 ON A2.ID=B.ID
                      WHERE a2.ID = a1.ID) -- link back to the ID of the row we are updating!
```

OK, and now we can add back in the check for a matching B row for this update, in that case we can avoid rejoining to A as it is unneccessary and just use the record we are working on

```
UPDATE A a1
SET a1.AMT =   (SELECT A2.AMT * B.QTY AS tot_amt
                  FROM B 
                    JOIN A A2 ON A2.ID=B.ID
                      WHERE a2.ID = a1.ID) 
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 
           FROM B b2
           WHERE b2.ID=a1.ID)
```

I have to wonder if there isn't more that you need to do though as far as null checking or zero checking to get this to work the way you want it to for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the query Michael but the query still returns the same error: "single-row subquery returns more than one row". Any clue on that?

Comment: This is the query that I am working on:
UPDATE RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_ALL_WD a1
SET a1.EXTENDED_AMOUNT =   
(SELECT a2.EXTENDED_AMOUNT * nvl(ra_cust_trx_line_salesreps_WD.revenue_percent_split,100)/100 AS EXT_AMOUNT
                 FROM ra_cust_trx_line_salesreps_WD 
                    JOIN RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_ALL_WD a2 
     ON a2.customer_trx_line_id = ra_cust_trx_line_salesreps_WD.customer_trx_line_id 
          where a2.customer_trx_line_id = a1.customer_trx_line_id)
where exists
(select 1 from ra_cust_trx_line_salesreps_WD b2
where b2.customer_trx_line_id = a1. customer_trx_line_id);

Comment: So that subquery is returning more than one value for at least one a1 record, which should be demonstrable by running: select customer_trx_line_id, count(1) from RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_ALL_WD group by customer_trx_line_id having count(1) > 1 to get the offending line_ids.

Comment: Once you find the offending data, the question becomes is it bad data? Or if it is good data then how to modify the subquery to bring back the correct value as a single row. You will have to figure that out based on the business rules on how to calculate the total for a set of revenue split records.